# как повернуть матрицу на 90 градусов

Tags: c#

[image: как повернуть это изображение на 90 градусов]

что я имею:

```
        static void PutPixel(int x, int y, int codeColor)
        {
            ConsoleColor color = (ConsoleColor)codeColor;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.Write("█");
        }
        static void DrawImageColor(int x, int y, int[,] image)
        {
            // по строчкам
            for (int i = 0; i < image.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                // по столбцам
                for (int j = 0; j < image.GetLength(1); j++)
                {

                    PutPixel(x + j, y + i, image[i, j]);
                    //  Console.Write(image[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }



static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            int[,] mas2 =
            {
                {00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 10, 01, 10, 01, 10, 7, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 12, 00, 00, 00, 00, 10, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 10, 00, 00, 00, 00, 7, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 12, 00, 00, 00, 00, 10, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 10, 01, 01, 01, 01, 7, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 12, 00, 00, 00, 00, 10, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 10, 00, 00, 00, 00, 7, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 12, 00, 00, 00, 00, 10, 00, 00, 00},
                {00, 10, 00, 00, 00, 00, 7, 00, 00, 00}
            };
            DrawImageColor(10, 10, mas2);        
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Переписать значения в новую матрицу, для каждой исходной позиции рассчитав новые координаты. Например, `0,0` перейдёт в `0, size-1` и так далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ - это переписать элементы в новый массив. И работать будет для матриц любого размера, не только квадратных.

```
private static int[,] Rotate90(int[,] matrix)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    int[,] result = new int[cols, rows];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            result[col, rows - row - 1] = matrix[row, col];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
mas2 = Rotate90(mas2); // 90 градусов по часовой стрелке
```

Answer (score 0):

Меняем местами пиксели по кругу и все дела, пример для квадратной матрицы

```
public void Rotate(int[][] matrix)
{
    var n = matrix.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        var side = n - 2 * i - 1;
        var row = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < side; j++)
        {
            var col = i + j;

            var v1 = matrix[row][col];              

            matrix[row][col] = matrix[n - 1 - col][row];
            matrix[n - 1 - col][row] = matrix[n - 1 - row][n - 1 - col];
            matrix[n - 1 - row][n - 1 - col] = matrix[col][n - 1 - row];
            matrix[col][n - 1 - row] = v1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на строке matrix[row, col] = matrix[n - 1 - col, row]; пишет индекс находился вне границ массива

Comment: Значит вы что то не так делаете. Этот код проверен многократно. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: @yeah вы пытаетесь применить код от зубчатого массива, написанного выше к двумерному. Будьте внимательней. `[][]` != `[,]`

Comment: @yeah предположу проблему тут `var n = matrix.Length;`, с двумерным массивом должно быть что то типа `var n = matrix.GetLength(0);`